# String values in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Java, if we do `new String()`  we know it would create new string object and it would be different from the object created without 'new'(even if contents are same).

```
//Java    
System.out.println("First" == new String("First")); // false always
```

In Kotlin, if I try to create String even by creating StringBuilder, it would still be identical to that created without String(..).

```
//Kotlin
println("First" == String(StringBuilder("First"))) //true always
```

If the created `String(StringBuilder(..))` is going to reuse same string value, why give constructor? Does it do any value add, looking for such use-case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the `==` operator you're checking structural equality between the strings (whether they represent the same sequence of characters). The Java equivalent of your Kotlin comparison code above would be something like this:

```
Object.equals("First", new String(new StringBuilder("First"))); // true
```

To check reference equality in Kotlin, you need to use the `===` operator.

Check out the Kotlin reference on [Equality](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html).

Answer (score 5):

In Java when you use operator `==` you use *referential equality*. However, in Kotlin it is *structural equality*.

To use referential equality in Kotlin you need to use `===` operator.

You can check this doc page for more information: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Answer (score 1):

To use referential equality you need to use === operator in kotlin.
In java == operator use for referential equality. but in kotlin it is structural equality.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `==` is **referential equality**, but in Kotlin `==` is **structural equality**. That means, in Kotlin `==` and `string1.equals(string2)` both do the same thing. And in Kotlin we use `===` for **referential equality**.